# Is there an easy to integrate java-based forum software available

Tags: java, forum

Integration via Hibernate, Acegi, Spring, Tiles would be superb.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [JavaBB](http://www.javabb.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I like [JForum](http://jforum.net/) See the [feature list](http://jforum.net/features.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

simply compare them [JavaBB vs JForum vs MVN Forum vs Yazd](http://www.forum-software.org/forum-comparator/javabb-vs-jforum-vs-mvn-forum-vs-yazd).

My personal choice would be, however, [JForum](http://www.forum-software.org/jforum/review), that is far more powerful.